# Throwing exceptions in other classes

Tags: java, exception, runtimeexception

I need to make changes to two classes. so, that exceptions are thrown when necessary. And, I have a class in the program called `CheckEmptyException` and it extends `RuntimeException`.  Where do I make these changes to the other two classes?  In the classes there are two methods called `public boolean isEmpty()`.

Comment: What classes are you trying to change?  If they're not yours, you can't change them without unleashing unspeakable horrors.  You probably want to extend those classes and override `isEmpty()`

Comment: post your code, it's hard to guess what you are trying to do

Comment: use "throw CheckEmptyException" where you want to and catch it to do what you want to